# Problem running jest: Error: Do not import `@jest/globals` outside of the Jest test environment

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to use Jest.js to test some typescript code I wrote.  I am getting an error "Error: Do not import `@jest/globals` outside of the Jest test environment" but I thought I was in a jest testing environment.  Here is my code:

```
import {NewMarketContractRequest, NewContractReponse, MarketSalesDataReply, MessageResonse} from '../models';
import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals';

import {deployNewMarketContract} from '../market-contract-lib';

describe('deployNewMarketContract', () => {
    it('should deploy a new market contract', async () => {
        var request: NewMarketContractRequest = {
            contractId: 'market3.testnet',
            ownerAccount: 'market3.testnet',
            ftTokenIds: [],
            chainId: 'testnet',
            toJSON: () => {return "";},
            toObject: () => { return new Object();}
        };
        const response = await deployNewMarketContract(request);
        expect(response.id).toBeDefined();
        expect(response.createdTime).toBeDefined();
        expect(response.chainId).toBeDefined();
        expect(response.transactionHash).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

And when I run "npm test" this is what I get:

```
Error: Do not import `@jest/globals` outside of the Jest test environment
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\s\keypom-api\node_modules\@jest\globals\build\index.js:12:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\s\keypom-api\src\__tests__\market-contract-tests.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

This test file is the only one that references jest at all so the error message doesn't even seem correct to me.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to import jest globals, they will be available in your testing environment, as [the documentation](https://%20https://jestjs.io/docs/api) states:

> In your test files, Jest puts each of these methods and objects into
> the global environment. You don't have to require or import anything
> to use them. However, if you prefer explicit imports, you can do
> `import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals'`.

You just need to create test files, by default they are

- `.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts` and `.tsx` files inside of `__tests__` folders,
- Any files with a suffix of `.test` or `.spec` (e.g. `Component.test.js` or `Component.spec.js`)
- Files called `test.js` or `spec.js`

So just delete `import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals'` from your test files as the error message says.

If you had some warnings in your editor with TypeScript it's just because of Jest's typescript definitions, you can just install [`@types/jest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jest) with

```
npm i -D @types/jest
```

Comment: expect.anything() doesn't work unless I import jest globals and then tests that run say 'don't import jest globals' - installing the types doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: "You don't have to import jest globals" ... only by default, see [`injectGlobals`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#injectglobals-boolean).

Comment: I'm getting reference errors for describe, so I don't think it's auto injecting them.